# get all the friends and all mutual friends with graph-api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get all friends of a user, and mutual friends. I'm using Graph API V2.4.
first I used  `... /me/friends` but i  discover this method return only friends with use my app. I read that is used `.../me/taggable_friends` and returned all friends, but not return id friend, return other id.
I read about all_mutual_friends but I cannot use this method because i dont have friend ids.
Anybody know any solution ?

Comment: You are simply not supposed to get “all friends” any more. Friends that are using the app as well is what you get, and that’s it. So see to it that you make do with that, as all other apps have to as well.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there's no workaround for this , you can't access a user's friends list .

However if you can access his news feed you can iterate over his posts and get the json array of the likes of each one and combine them  , by doing this you at least have some of the user's friends IDs .
The request goes something like this
Get /{post id}?fields=likes

Comment: It's bad news.
With crawler i can solve my problem but don't like this solution.